# Using Hopscotch to autoplay tour and have it never play again after closed/done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hopscotch

The [Hopscotch example tour](http://linkedin.github.io/hopscotch) sets up the parameters and calls `hopscotch.startTour(tour);` however neither the close "x" nor the "Done" buttons seem to prevent it from playing again after the page loads.

How can that be accomplished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of localstorage/cookie on the onend function.

```
function setCookie(key, value) {
    var expires = new Date();
    expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    document.cookie = key + '=' + value + ';path=/' + ';expires=' + expires.toUTCString();
};

function getCookie(key) {
    var keyValue = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + key + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
    return keyValue ? keyValue[2] : null;
};

var tour = {
    onEnd: function() {
        setCookie("toured", "toured");
    },
    onClose: function() {
        setCookie("toured", "toured");
    }
};

// Initialize tour if it's the user's first time
if (!getCookie("toured")) {
    hopscotch.startTour(tour);
}
```